# 'Selecting' buttons on a CSS Navbar using SSI

Tags: html, css, class, navbar, ssi

I'm working on a site and I'm using SSI to attach a banner/menu/footer to each page on my website. The problem I'm having is showing the 'selected' state on the menu for each different page.

Just to avoid confusion, the entire navbar is one image at a fixed height/width and a position that changes to change button state.

**What I have so far:**

index.html

```
<!--#include virtual="./global_header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="./global_footer.html" -->

    /**Yeah, that's it for index.html at the moment. Like I said, a work in progress**/
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE...

<div class="s_container" id="s_menu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li id="menu_borderl"><p>[</p></li>
        <li id="menu_home"><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu_forum"><a href="/forum/" title="Forum">Forum</a></li>
        <li id="menu_apply"><a href="apply.html" title="Apply">Apply</a></li>
        <li id="menu_about"><a href="about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu_borderr"><p>]</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>...
```

CSS:

```
ul#navbar {
    width:1000px;
    list-style:none;
    height:76px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul#navbar li {
    display:inline;
}

ul#navbar li a {
    height:76px;
    float:left;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

ul#navbar li p {
    height:76px;
    float:left;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin:0px;
}

/**HOME**/
/**I have these once for each button, with the correct x,y for the bg position**/
ul#navbar li#menu_home a {
    width:205px;
    background:url(images/menu_buttons.png) no-repeat -75px 0;
}
ul#navbar  li#menu_home a:hover {
    background-position:-75px -76px; 
}
ul#navbar  li#menu_home a.current {
    background-position:-75px -152px;
}
```

If I add `class="current"` to any li it works as intended.

Now for my question, and sorry if it's obvious, but I'm pretty new to this. Is there any way I can place some code in 'index.html' to add the 'current' class to a given line item? Thanks for any help, and sorry if it's terribly obvious. If you need more information, please let me know.

**SOLVED**

Since I'm new I can't answer my question for another couple of hours, but here's what I'm gonna post:

**EDIT**

Changed a bit in the code that goes into index.html per leftclickbens suggestion to get rid of !important

*So I figured it out. for the example above i removed*

```
ul#navbar  li#menu_home a.current {
    background-position:-75px -152px;
}
```

*from the CSS file and added*

```
ul#navbar li#menu_home a, ul#navbar li#menu_home a:hover {
    background-position:-75px -152px;
}
```

*into index.html (between the SSIs)*

Comment: In response to your self-solution, you can do the same without resorting to `!important`.  Just change the selector from `ul#navbar li#menu_home a.current` to `ul#navbar li#menu_home a.current, ul#navbar li#menu_home a.current:hover`.  This is preferred over use of `!important`.  The reason it works is that `ul#navbar li#menu_home a.current:hover` is more specific than the previous rule, `ul#navbar  li#menu_home a:hover`, so it wins out.

Comment: Thanks for that. Updated the solution to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a bit in the code that goes into index.html per leftclickbens suggestion to get rid of !important

So I figured it out. for the example above i removed

```
ul#navbar  li#menu_home a.current {
    background-position:-75px -152px;
}
```

from the CSS file and added

```
ul#navbar li#menu_home a, ul#navbar li#menu_home a:hover {
    background-position:-75px -152px;
}
```

into index.html (between the SSIs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'static' server side includes, as opposed to a dynamic server-side language like PHP, then your best bet is to look at JavaScript methods of highlighting the current page.  There are plenty of plugins available, depending on what framework you are using (e.g. jQuery), or if your requirements are simple you might get by with some simple regular expression matching.

Comment: I'm open to use whatever. I already have PHP installed and can (figure out how to) use that instead if you think it better?

Comment: Well, it would depend on your overall requirements, how much code you've written, how much would need to change, etc.  If you look into PHP, you should check out the many component libraries and frameworks.  I personally like Symfony Components, which is not a framework, so it allows you to code as you like, but provides some very useful classes and tools, which you can pick and choose from.  This is much more powerful than SSI but be aware it is also a step up for your skill requirements :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I figured out a solution. I've added it in the question until I can answer it myself, in 6 hours. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Also, I'll look into Symfony Components before I do any real php on the site, It looks interesting. And I'll be sure to vote up when I can, not enough rep yet =P